# Docker multistage build Issues

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

My Current Docker file looks like below . I'm trying to use h2o as a base for my ML model service .Now h2o requires JRE and i'm forced to install the required packages for my flask script . It was as heavy as 1.8 Gig so attempted multi-stage build (script below )

```html
#Original Docker File 
FROM h2oai/h2o-open-source-k8s

MAINTAINER rajesh.r6r@gmail.com

USER root

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install python-pip -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* # remove the cached files

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5005
EXPOSE 54321

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I attempted doing multi-stage builds as follows , but this only results in a python image skipping the h2o part . What am I Missing ?

```html
#Multi-Stage Docker File 
FROM h2oai/h2o-open-source-k8s AS baseimage

FROM python:3.7-slim

USER root

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5005
EXPOSE 54321

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: The place a multi-stage build helps is if installing the package needs a full C toolchain or other specialized tools, but you don't need them to run the image.  I don't see anything obvious like that in your initial Dockerfile.  The typical multi-stage build pattern is to have a first stage `FROM` some larger image, and a final stage `FROM` an image including your runtime dependencies, that can `COPY --from=build` built files.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze Thanks for the feedback . This kind of makes some sense now . So I guess I cannot reduce the size . If I come across anything I'll comment back .

Comment: Hi David , I did some research and found that the h2o docker image that I was using uses ubuntu as a base image . I tried Alpine but it's not a good idea considering issues it has with Python Packages . Any suggestions for a light-weight option . By the way my image is here 

https://hub.docker.com/r/rajeshr6routlook/h2o_base_image